# Android 4.2 Stock browser. Canvas clearRect() sometimes doesn't work

Tags: javascript, android, canvas, webview

So I have a problem with `clearRect` in js-canvas-animation. This problem happens only on Android API 16, and only in the moment when animation is restart.

I'm using `setInterval()` for my animation (here is simplify code)

```
function start() {   
    clearInterval(animationInterval);
    x = 0;
    canvas = document.getElementById("animationCanvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    animationInterval = setInterval(func, 30);
}

function func() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillRect(halfWidth - x, 0, 250, 150);
    x += extensionStep;
}
```

It is look like a shore. But every time, when i restart animation with help start function, under new animation i see last frame previous animation. Already i was trying `beginPath()`, `save`, `stroke`. I check all question on SO and nothing.

How i can clear the background under animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after several hours, i found one of the solves. It is strange bug for old android, because new android (i checked on api 24) it fixed. For hard cleaning you can detach canvas from DOM and reattach again:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
canvas.style.display = 'none';// Detach from DOM
canvas.offsetHeight; // Force the detach
canvas.style.display = 'inherit'; // Reattach to DOM
```

It is simple operation and is not resource intensive.